# Webpack does not recognize image inserted with jQuery attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I first created an Electron app which worked without any problems and now I want to transfer it to Webpack.
But now I'm facing the problem that everything works so far, but my images, which I added with the jQuery attr command, are not loaded.

Error Message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

jQuery inside html file:

```
$('#slide1').attr("src","./images/example_image.png");
```

Is there anything I need to consider in connection with jQuery attr and Webpack or where could be the error?

Comment: 404 means, image not found, check the location of your image.

Comment: The image is located in this folder and I have also tried several possibilities of this path. The thing is that it works with a normal <img src="./images/example_image.png"> in the HTML. But with jQuery attr it doesn't work.